# How can I lift an element one level higher, above the parent, using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a problem, i have a lot of span inside their fahter element p, that i want is to convert them in p, and put them first of their parent, like the example code:
initail code:

```
<p class="text"><span class="textTitle">Lorem ipsum </span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.</p>

<p class="text">Li Europan lingues es membres del sam familie. Lor separat existentie es un myth. Por scientie, musica, sport etc, litot Europa usa li sam vocabular. Li lingues differe solmen in li grammatica, li pronunciation e li plu commun vocabules.</p>

<p class="text"><span class="textTitle">Sed ut perspiciatis </span>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.</p>
```

the result I wish it was like this:

```
<p class="textTitle">Lorem ipsum </p>
<p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.</p>

<p class="text">Li Europan lingues es membres del sam familie. Lor separat existentie es un myth. Por scientie, musica, sport etc, litot Europa usa li sam vocabular. Li lingues differe solmen in li grammatica, li pronunciation e li plu commun vocabules.</p>

<p class="textTitle">Sed ut perspiciatis </p>
<p class="text">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.</p>
```

I can post my xslt, but don't work:

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="//p[contains(@class,'text')]">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="//span[contains(@class,'textTitle')]"/>
    <p class="textTitle"><xsl:apply-template></p>
<xsl:template>
```

I work with xhtml and not with xml, my doctype is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Comment: Please show your current XSLT stylesheet and point out where it fails. Also, your input and output samples must be well-formed, complete XML documents.

Comment: i have edited the post with my not-working xslt.

Comment: That's only half of what I was asking for I'm afraid. Post a complete XSLT stylesheet and complete XML samples, following the rules laid out here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Can you try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10310665/how-to-remove-some-tags-without-removing-the-content-in-xslt-and-pass-entire-con

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've taken your example code (which was not proper XML, so it could not possibly be used for anything, but I fixed it). If you change it as follows, it outputs what you want based on the info you gave in the question:

```
<!-- assuming XSLT 1.0, but runs equally well with XSLT 2.0 -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'
    exclude-result-prefixes="x">

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="x:p[@class = 'text']">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="x:span[@class='textTitle']" />
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::x:span[@class='textTitle'])]" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="x:span[@class='textTitle']">
        <p class="textTitle"><xsl:value-of select="." /></p>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This generates the following result, given your input:

```
<p class="textTitle">Lorem ipsum </p><p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.</p>

<p class="text">Li Europan lingues es membres del sam familie. Lor separat existentie es un myth. Por scientie, musica, sport etc, litot Europa usa li sam vocabular. Li lingues differe solmen in li grammatica, li pronunciation e li plu commun vocabules.</p>

<p class="textTitle">Sed ut perspiciatis </p><p class="text">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.</p>
```

Of course, as often in programming, there are more ways to do this.

Please note some comments on your original code:

> ```
> <xsl:template match="//span[contains(@class,'postilla')]"/>
> ```

There is no `postilla` in your example, so this will never hit. Also, starting a match pattern with `//` is not illegal, but it also has no effect, other than being detrimental to performance.

> ```
> <xsl:template match="//p[contains(@class,'text')]">
> ```

Instead of `contains()`, you probably wanted `=` here, as in `[@class = 'text']`. And same comment as above for the `//`.

---

EDIT: after your edit it became clear that you have trouble processing your source, which appears to be XHTML.

Elements in XHTML are in a namespace: `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml`. Just add the following to the main stylesheet declaration: `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` so that any literal result elements are in the correct namespace, and add `xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` as well, and prefix each element name in any XPath expression or pattern.

I have updated the code above to reflect this.

Note: if you use XSLT 2.0, you can fix this also with `xpath-default-namespace`.

Comment: You are assuming the `span` in question contains no markup.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: indeed, I was assuming that from the input data. But instead of `xsl:value-of`, it is probably better to use `xsl:apply-templates`, I've adjusted it.

Comment: So, your solution don'work, the result is the same thing of the input file, and the xslt, that is very similar of yours, have the same result.

Comment: @antlego: the result is what I showed, which is 100% equal to what you requested in your original question (tested against your input data), except perhaps for a newline, which is irrelevant in XML and HTML. It is also equal to Michael's result. Can you be more precise to what you want differently? Does your result differ from what I showed here, if so, what did you do differently?

Comment: i dont't know, now i edit the original message and give you the original code, with my real classes and the xslt that i have modified after yours tips.

Comment: @Abel: there is some problem with my original code, may be that in my origin file thr tree is more compless? this is one of the reason because i use the match pattern //. i don't know why if i apply he xslt on the code in my question it works, but on my original xhtml file don't work

Comment: @antlego, as I tried to explain in my post, there is hardly ever a need for starting a pattern `//` (unless you want to distinguish between rooted and non-rooted nodes, but that is an advanced subject, or unless it is a pattern not in a global template). Your code will work equally well without them.

Comment: @antlego: I have updated the answer, see at the bottom and the changed code. As a tip for the future: if you give a complete (minimal) example in your original post, in this case including root element and namespaces, it is easier to help you and understand the issue. See also [mcve] :).

Comment: @Abel Thank's a lot, the last solution working well. I often find solutions other than for-each or if, but i'm a newbe and don't fully understand xslt, but I appreciate its power. ;-)

Comment: @antlego: whenever you find yourself using `xsl:for-each` on nodes, you can replace it with `xsl:apply-templates`, which reduces nesting. Most cases with `xsl:if` can be replaced by using `xsl:apply-templates`, which in itself only has effect if the conditions in the selection (the predicate in square brackets) are met. These constructs have most merit when used with non-nodes, though this limitation was lifted in XSLT 3.0. This principle with using templates is called _declarative programming_.

Answer (score 1):

This will work for your example:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p[@class='text']">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="span[@class='textTitle']"/>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[not(self::span[@class='textTitle'])]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="span[@class='textTitle']">
    <p class="textTitle">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </p>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I did not see `span[contains(@class,'postilla')]` anywhere in your input.

Comment: sorry 'postilla' was 'textTitle'

Comment: Intriguing to see how remarkably close our two answers are, independently written.

Comment: @Abel I don't think there's much room for variation here. The intriguing part is that we both decided to replace `contains()` with `=`.

Comment: Well, people have the tendency to use `xsl:if` and `xsl:for-each` to solve every problem imperatively, but I wouldn't have expected from you, but I was nevertheless surprised ;).

Comment: @michael.hor257k many thank's to you too, you made me understand another piece of the XSLT :-)